# Extracrting high intensity objects from grayscale image

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, feature-extraction, infrared

My data is grayscale images taken from an IR camera. The objects I'm interested in have a higher intensity than the background. One problem is that the contrast between the object to its background changes from picture to picture.
Another problem is that my object's value range can change. for example, the object can be in the range [170,255], and at other times in the range [70,255], or any other range. The only certainty is that the object will be with the highest intensity values in the image.

My goal is to extract the object and match it to familiar objects from my data set.

The first step I did is thresholding the images. The threshold is determined by the cumulative sum of the histogram of each image by creating a "cumulative histogram" and normalizing it. Next, I take the value of the x-axis that corresponds to the value 0.93 in the y-axis and that x value is my threshold.

Testing it on my data yields great results in filtering the objects, but still, there is some noise that doesn't get filtered out.

[the images and the thresholded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiZJb.png)

My question is what do you suggest to do in order to achive my goal from the point I'm at. I have thresholded images but from this point I can't extract exactly the object, it's always with noise, or if I try to filter the noise, some parts of the objects also get filtered.

Comment: I edited it so my question is more clear now.

Comment: You have shared montaged plots of the images with axes and labels rather than actual images - it doesn't make it very easy to process them.

Comment: I tried to upload the links for the images, the algorithm thought it was spam. I'll try here : https://ibb.co/bJgWQTD
https://ibb.co/60ZbKCB
https://ibb.co/v491fPx
https://ibb.co/R4vKHzS
https://ibb.co/2vdkKrJ
https://ibb.co/mS7mNfg
https://ibb.co/bB08W3n
https://ibb.co/T0gR2nf
https://ibb.co/1zzBLw8
https://ibb.co/pQzQ7C9
https://ibb.co/M5Q9bQn
https://ibb.co/khv6XNw
https://ibb.co/wyKH9RR
https://ibb.co/JppwTcp
https://ibb.co/nQCCGsX
https://ibb.co/tzBRbSg
https://ibb.co/nCrPssC
https://ibb.co/pLsdpS4
https://ibb.co/bB5SjfW
https://ibb.co/q74gkJK

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance to everyone for your effort and help.